# XSL-FO: Adjust border-width based on text width

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am having trouble with XSL-FO using Apache FOP as a processor. I have a simple stylesheet and already have set a round border to an fo:block-container. The problem is: the text size is non-predictable given that the .fo file will be generated using a XSLT and a XML, so i need to tell FOP to adjust the border width according to the text width instead of  applying the same width to all of the containers. Any ideas?

> In XSLT file:

```
    <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="right-side-itens">
        <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="rounded-borders">                                    
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of-select="./tagInsideXML/@attribute" />
                <!-- qwertyuiopasdfghjkl -->
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    <fo:block-container>
```

`

> In the styles.xsl external file:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="right-side-itens">
    <xsl:attribute name="top">35px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="right">45px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">end</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">10px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="height">10cm</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="width">200px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="position">absolute</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<xsl:attribute-set name="rounded-borders">
    <xsl:attribute name="margin-top">2px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="margin-right">1.8px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-right">2px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="float">right</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="line-height">18px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">8px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border">solid 1.2px #000000</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="fox:border-radius">6px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="position">relative</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="overflow">visible</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

[Here is a sample image showing the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjSCJ.png)

Comment: Can you give more details, such as sample XSL-FO or a screenshot and explanation of what's currently going wrong?

Comment: Hi there, I added a sample code and an edited image to clarify my goals. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A block-container usually has a fixed size, while a block can grow with its contents. So I'd put an fo:block inside the container, and apply the border to that block.

Comment: Already tried this and what is happening is that the border always adjust it's width to the largest tag that contains the fo:block, so for example applying the border to the fo:block inside the fo:container makes the border width the same as the fo:container width, but take the fo:container off and you will see that now the border width is the same as in the fo:region-body.

Comment: don't have my dev machine handy right now, but you could check if an fo:inline supports borders...

Comment: They do support borders, but the width still fitting within the largest container.